# generating an unique string based on user id

Tags: php

I need to convert user db id or username (or whatever else is unique for each account) to an unique 3-5 character string with characters and/or numbers.

Example:
id 12481 would look like HJ28.

It should work both ways, so when HJ28 is given I can convert it back to the number. What would be the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: This would never work one-to-one because there are more names that can be mapped to a 3-5 character string. It is just not possible to go back to the username. What are you trying to achieve? There might be a better answer if you share.

Comment: It will work for DB ID if the ID is less than 60 million (assuming using the base 36 solution).

Comment: If you can explain for what you need this, it should be easier to answer (and if I smell it right, this has already been asked and answered well, so just share a bit more).

Comment: @hakre I want to assign each user a referral link without revealing any info in the string...

Comment: @domino: security through obscurity does not add anything. If you reveal the string, you are revealing information

Comment: Just search the site, this has been asked before under the php tag. Additionally this will only prevent very little, e.g. trivial counting up / down. But you're good to go to look into multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your id is numeric, you can pass it to base 255 and store the chars. If the chars are too weird, you can use a base 36 (letters + numbers) and it will reduce the amount of characters finally needed.

The idea is to use the same as converting the number "10" (two chars) in decimal to hex will give you "a" (one char). Using base 36 or 255 will "compress" a lot your id.

Answer (score 0):

12481 <-> A2D8A maybe ? Or you can choose anything else.